# How to stack diffrent layout objects, over each other?

Tags: android, textview, android-tabhost, tablerow, invisible

Hello Guys and probably some Girls, is it possible to stack Layout Objects. So that one Object is over the other one?
My Problem is this, i've got a tabhost and under the tabhost i've got a tablerow with a textview in it.

I made the tabhost tabs invisible, but it hiddes my tablrow with the textview in it,how can i bring it infront?

Here is the Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <RelativeLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >
       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBottom = "@android:id/tabcontent" 
           android:visibility="invisible"/>

       <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/ADFilterOverview" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:onClick="onClickADConfig" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

           <TextView 
                android:text="@string/newadfilter" 
                style="@style/NormalFont" 
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left">
           </TextView>
       </TableRow>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Thx in Advance

Best Regards
safari

Some more information, for better understanding:

Afterwards my code of my Activity looks something like this:

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit;

    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class StatsActivity extends TabActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.stats);
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();       

            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("whatever").setContent(new Intent(this, SFilterStatsActivity.class)));
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

        }

    /** Verweise auf die anderen Seiten **/
public void onClickADConfig(View view){
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, ADFilterConfigActivity.class);
    startActivity(i); }


    }
```

The linked class from my Tabhost looks for example like this:

```
    package de.retowaelchli.filterit;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class ADFilterStatsActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListContent));   
    }  

    private static String[] mListContent={"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3","Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3","Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3","Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
}
```

So you see, i got a TabHost with one tab in it, which is filled from my ListActivity, the tabhost should be hidden (invisible), over this hidden tab should be the tablerow visible. So i can click it to get to my other class.
I hope this helps you guys...

FOUND A SOLUTION THX [Egon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543539/egor)

And here is the solution

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >



       <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBottom = "@android:id/tabcontent" 
           android:visibility="invisible"/>
       <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ADFilterOverview" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:onClick="onClickADConfig" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
           <TextView android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" android:text="@string/newadfilter" style="@style/NormalFont"></TextView>
       </TableRow>
       </RelativeLayout>
      </TabHost>


  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: why are you make your TabHost invisible?

Comment: i only have one Tab, which is allways activ and filled with content from a ListActivity which is filled from a database. I need the Tablerow to get to the next Activity where i can set the Content for my database, which is afterwards showen in this Tabhost =)  I hope you understand

Comment: since you always have on tab, why do you use a TabHost?

Comment: from my understanding of your line "I made the tabhost tabs invisible, but it hiddes my tablrow with the textview in it,how can i bring it infront?" If you make any parent view invisible then its child views are also automatically made invisible. :-) (If I m not wrong?) Thanx.

Comment: i dunno, i dont know an other way to realize something like that. I'm really new to android.. started working with it 2weeks ago :D, thats not a lot. @user370305 but than i don't even see the content of my tab in it, or am i wrong.? and the placeholder is still there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make Parentview invisible then its childview also automatically make invisible. In this scenario you have to define other layout for your new tab.

If this is not correct, please make edit in, or suggest me. Thanx

EDIT: on your xml code I think tabhost is a parentview and tablerow , textview are childview of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place one `View` at the top of the other in Z-axis, you can use `FrameLayout`. It lets you position a `View` on the background and other views on top of it. It's really powerful and easy to use, so you must give it a try. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for your help. I got a FrameLayout in it, how can i get it in the background??

Comment: @safari, The first view placed inside FrameLayout is always the background view, all the others are at foreground. Of course you can create nested layouts to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hmm, i'm still trying to do this :(), how should the layout look like ?

Comment: @safari, Here's a nice post that will be helpful to you:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Comment: I rememberd you in this post =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you set the tabwidget to be alignParentBottom and then you set TableRow to have aligntop the tabwidget. Thus it is not visible. Making the tabwidget invisible does hide it, but the place holder is still there.